# How to check if two convex hulls have intersection in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, intersection, convex-hull

Say I have two convex hulls like this.

```
C=convhull(x1, y1); 
D=convhull(x2, y2);
```

where x1,y1,x2,y2 are vectors.

Now I can plot these two convex hulls, but how can I know if these two convex hulls have intersection? I want it in a program, not visually, since I plan to use this in another `.m` file.

Note: This is all in matlab.

Comment: Do you have access to the Mapping toolbox?  You can use [`polyxpoly`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html).

Comment: No I don't have that.

Comment: you can apply Sutherland-Hodgman see here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sutherland-Hodgman_polygon_clipping#MATLAB_.2F_Octave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way, although not necessarily the most efficient, is to use [inpolygon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html).

```
C=convhull(x1, y1); 
D=convhull(x2, y2);

xC = x1(C); yC = y1(C);
xD = x2(D); yD = y2(D);
CinD = inpolygon(xC, yC, xD, yD);
DinC = inpolygon(xD, yD, xC, yC);
```

If you're just looking for a binary yes/no answer as to whether the two polygons intersect,

```
CDintersect = any(CinD) || any(DinC);
```

If you need the actual points, `CinD` contains the indices for `xC,yC` and `DinC` contains the indices for `xD,yD`.

While this doesn't require any toolboxes, it does require checking all of the points on both convex hulls, although you can shortcut that if `CinD` contains any points and you're just looking for a yes/no answer.